# Determining the minimum number of matchups needed to simulate a round-robin tournament in a many-versus-many matchup system

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I stumbled upon this problem while running Mariokart tournaments during my undergrad. In a normal competition where there are 1v1 matchups, a round robin tournament is always done in $m(n) = \frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$ matches, as each participant must play every other participant once, and a matchup of $A \rightarrow B$ also satisfies $B \rightarrow A$.

However I find it difficult figuring out the minimum number of matchups possible in any arbitrary $m_i(n)$ , where $i \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ is the number of participants in a matchup in the round-robin tournament. First I'll discern what it even means for two participants to satisfyingly play in a tournament where $i > 1$.

For participants $a, b$ in a tournament with $i$ participants per match, $a$ has played $b$ if $a$ and $b$ have both been participants in the same matchup. For example, in a 4v4 free-for-all matchup tournament with participants $P = \{ a, b, c, d, e, f, g\}$, the matchups 1 = $\{a, b, c, d\}$, 2 = $\{ e, f, g, h \}$, 3 = $\{ a, b, e, f\}$ would satisfy the round-robin requirements like so:

|  | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | - | - |
| b | - | x | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | - | - |
| c | - | - | x | 1 | - | - | - | - |
| d | - | - | - | x | - | - | - | - |
| e | - | - | - | - | x | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| f | - | - | - | - | - | x | 2 | 2 |
| g | - | - | - | - | - | - | x | 2 |
| h | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | x |

Ah! this looks familiar to our $\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$ round robin matchups equation from before. Perhaps we could work backwards to find the minimum. That is, start with *all* possible matchups and prune matchups until we arrive at a point in which we cannot prune any more matchups and still have the round-robin requirement met.

So what is the size of that maximally un-optimal set? It would be defined by leting our set of participants $A$ and a positive integer representing the size of a matchup $m$, then the set of all possible $m$ matchups would be subset $S$ of the powerset of $P(A)$ such that for each $S_i, S_j \in S$ $|S_i| = |S_j| = m$. Or put simpler, the number of unique combinations of length $i$, which is just:

$$
_nC_i = \frac{n!}{i!(n - i)!}
$$

Now the part I'm stuck on is how exactly we'd deduce pruning "redundant" matchups. Has anyone encountered a problem like this before? Even if not, I would appreciate any other input. This problem has been haunting me for a while and I just can't seem to put it to rest!

Comment: This problem is hard. There is an optimal solution when we know a BIBD design. Otherwise, you should look for covering designs, there should be some asymptotic results and some explicit constructions.